# Ubuntu 14.04 and Win8 problem; no to LiveDVD

Tags: dual-boot

"1Create a LiveDVD or LiveUSB of Ubuntu (>=12.04.2) 64bit ONLY.

2In your BIOS, disable QuickBoot/FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT). If you have Windows8, also disable FastStartup.

3Boot your PC using the LiveDVD or LiveUSB and choose "Try Ubuntu". If you get a Secure boot or signature error, you may wish to disable SecureBoot, then retry to boot the disk.

4Install Ubuntu from the Live CD/DVD or Live USB in the usual manner, then reboot the PC."

I have completed steps 1-3 but but my HP pavilion will not boot to Ubuntu CD. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, reboot your PC and follow the on-screen instructions to enter your boot menu. Usually this is done by pressing Esc or F12. Then select CD-ROM from the option menu.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The UEFI was already setup to boot from cdrom first and HDD second.
Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit is already installed dual on my Dell Vista laptop, which has a broken hinge or I wouldn't be messing with a win8 machine. 
I was able to check iso disk with sha256sum and it gave Input/output error. The disk was burned on my HP win8 and is no good.
Downloading ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso file to Ubuntu on my Dell verified and was burned for a good bootable iso. 
All is well now. Problem solved. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't followed steps correctly, here is the link explains in detail..

[Install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1 in 10 easy steps](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)

Comment: @Apury, Thanks for responding. That article is one of ten that I read but I copied from shortest instr for space. Problem solved. See above. Now back to tour ref for final.